# When to capitalize Western?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality

Do I need to capitalize the word western when used to describe societies, such the phrase: "non-Western" societies?

Comment: Did you Google it?

Comment: @gotube sure, but still tricky for non-native.

Comment: I mean, just google the phrase "non-western" and see if the results have a capital "w" or not. That's easy enough

Comment: @gotube both variants can be found, so might even the natives don't know how to write it

Comment: @tac - that is the sort of thing people say when it is a matter of style.

Comment: @None When I do the search, every hit on the front page is the same, including some fairly reliable sites, like Google itself, Merriam-Webster, Wikipedia, JSTOR, The Guardian, and Britannica. Feels like you're not making any effort to find the answer yourself.

Comment: If you've done basic research but still find the issue tricky, [then you need to explain why and what the specific issue is](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please). We can't read your mind.

Comment: @gotube Google results are full of mistakes and I will find both variants. Knowing which is the right one needs asking credible language sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to "Western Civilization", then it is a proper noun and should be capitalized.

If you are using "western" generically as opposed to "eastern" (or some other direction), then it should not be capitalized.

"Western Civilization is dying." Proper noun, capitalized.

"The western part of town is dying." Not a proper noun, not capitalized.

Comment: The "C" in [Western civilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_culture) is not capitalised. I would probably capitalise it if I used it as a heading or title.

Comment: Interesting. In a brief web search I see it both ways. Like this page, https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/textbooks/698, capitalizes the "C". (Yes, when used as part of a title, but also when used in an ordinary sentence.) The Google ngram, https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/textbooks/698, shows not capitalizing the C as about 4 times as common.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate that you respond to my comments. However, first things first, the two links posted are identical but it doesn't matter in any case. An Ngram chart for *Western C/civilization* would also include book titles. Secondly, the word Western in your example has to be capitalized because it's at the beginning of a sentence.  Digging among Google books, I found the phrase [Western Hemisphere](https://tinyurl.com/mtsjb6t3) is nearly always capitalised in texts compared to [Western C/civilization](https://tinyurl.com/j6ddja8n) which, excluding book titles, is not always.

Comment: P.S I had to use tiny.url to shorten those Google books links, I hope that's OK. It seems to have worked! P.P.S If you search the British spelling "civilisation" it normally appears  in lowercase in the phrase.

Comment: @Mari-LouA RE Google ngram would include titles: True, and that would exaggerate the ratio of capital to small, but as the small greatly outnumbers the capital anyway, I don't think that matters much.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I messed up the ngram link. The correct link is https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Western+Civilization%2C+Western+civilization%2C+western+civilization&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: Note that I'm basically conceding the point. I assert that SOMETIMES it is written with a capital "C", but you are correct that it is usually written with a small "c".